# Counting question: distinct sums

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem: There are 8 cards with number 10  on them, 5  cards with number 100 on them and 2 cards with number 500 on them. How many distinct sums are possible using from 1 to all of the  cards?

Here is my solution, which is wrong: we can pick from 0 to 8 of the "10" cards, we can pick from 0 to 5 of the "100" cards and 0 to 2 of the "500" cards. This gives a total of 9*6*3 combos = 162 combos. But we have to exclude the 0,0,0 combo since we pick at least one card, and then we have to exclude the 0,5,0 combo since this is the same as 0,0,1. So this leaves 160 combos.

I have overcounted by 17 but I can't figure out why.

Comment: You are correct that you can reach 500 more than one way so you have to account for that.  The error you are making is that this duplicates more than one sum.  You can reach 500 two ways,  but also 510 two ways, and 520, two ways, etc.  You can still count the way you did and correct for the over counting (don't forget that there are also two ways to hit 1000)

It may very well be easier though just to count the numbers that you can actually reach

Comment: The $(n,5,0)$ combo is equivalent to the $(n,0,1)$ combo. You must remove $8$ of those.  And the $(n,5,1)$ combo is equivalent to the $(n,0,2)$ combo.

Comment: ah i forgot about that. thanks

Comment: Also if you have an easier direct counting method feel free to share, because I didn't see any easier way to do it directly